# Draw circle in center canvas and rotate view

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am drawing a circle in the center (+ some more that i'll leave out) on my own extension of a View. Then I add this to my layout, and in the onClickListener I increment the .setRotation(); But then my circle does not rotate around its center, it's slightly off. Why?

I have tried setting padding and margin to 0 but that doesn't change anything.

Minimal example:

```
public class MyCircleView extends View
{
private int width = 0;
private int height = 0;

public MyCircleView(Context context)
{
super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
width = w;
height = h;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
canvas.drawCircle(width/2, height/2, width/2, new Paint());
}
}
```

And then in main activity:

```
MyCircleView circle = new MyCircleView();
myLayout.addView(circle);

circle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
v.setRotation(v.getRotation()+10);
}});
```

Comment: could it be a rounding issue? maybe width isn't divisable by 2 and thereby the circle isn't exactly in the middle

Comment: Then it should be only 1 pixel difference. It is significantly more than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, a sneaky line of `width = width - 50;` was hiding in my code..